# How to execute blocks of functions?

Tags: javascript

This is my code:

```
var testStacks = new Array();

function test(elem) {
    console.log(elem);
    ... asynch operations
}

testStacks.push(test("hello 0"));
testStacks.push(test("hello 1"));
testStacks.push(test("hello 2"));
testStacks.push(test("hello 3"));
testStacks.push(test("hello 4"));

// init first 3 functions
testStacks[0];
testStacks[1];
testStacks[2];
```

and I want to execute 3 functions at time. So `hello 0`, `hello 1` and `hello 2` start together at the beginning. Than, once one function finish (they do asynch ops) it must calls the next one (not executed yet) from the array. And so on...

Seems that `testStacks[0]` does nothing, and when I push the function, it will be executed.

How can I do this? (I want to avoid `setInterval()`).

Comment: Have a look at **Promise.all()**. https://github.com/then/promise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple approach could be pushing both the function AND the parameters.

```
var testStacks = new Array();

function test(elem) {
    console.log(elem);
    ... asynch operations
}

testStacks.push({func: test, param: "hello 0"});
testStacks.push({func: test, param: "hello 1"});
testStacks.push({func: test, param: "hello 2"});
testStacks.push({func: test, param: "hello 3"});
testStacks.push({func: test, param: "hello 4"});

// init first 3 functions
testStacks[0].func(testStacks[0].param);
testStacks[1].func(testStacks[1].param);
testStacks[2].func(testStacks[2].param);
```

This could be generalized and cleaned up in many ways, of course, but should give you a basic idea.

Comment: But what about if I want to pop and execute the function? So I don't have index anymore (which can make confusion between asynch operation).

Comment: Using pop you will have to respect an order, from the top index to 0, Example:

`var f = testStacks.pop();
f.func(f.param);

f = testStacks.pop();
f.func(f.param);

f = testStacks.pop();
f.func(f.param);`

Comment: You could simply use `array.splice(index, 1)`  right after the execution. But this could mess a loop over the array if you're not careful.

Answer (score 2):

You are executing the function and pushing the return value. Push a function instead:

```
testStacks.push(function(){ test("hello 0"); });
```

Answer (score 1):

Whatever solution you'll choose, you'll need something like a third party object to manage the current call stack, and a way to notify this object whenever an operation is completed. Regarding the following (pretty dirty) code, I've decided to use a simple callback called from the `test` function :

```
var Stack = function (maxCalls, stack) {
    this.ongoing = 0;
    this.maxCalls = maxCalls;
    Array.prototype.push.apply(this, stack);
    this.next(); // starts immediately
};

Stack.prototype = Object.create(Array.prototype);

Stack.prototype.next = function () {
    var me = this;
    while (this.length && this.ongoing < this.maxCalls) {
        this.ongoing++;
        // calls the next function
        // passing a callback as a parameter
        this.shift()(function () {
            me.ongoing--;
            me.next();
        });
    }
};
```

See this demo for a use case : http://jsfiddle.net/wared/5eu8b/. As you can see, functions are called one after the other in a First In First Out way, but they complete in any order.

Hope it can help somehow :)